# Regarding loss weighting in Keras regression problem for multiple outputs

Tags: python, keras

I am running a Hyperas optimization for regression problem, with 3 predictors (X) and 2 targets (Y).

I did this, after ingesting the raw data:

```
X_train, X_val, Y_train, Y_val = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=111)

# Input layers and Hidden Layers
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense({{choice([np.power(2,1),np.power(2,2),np.power(2,3),np.power(2,4),np.power(2,5)])}}, input_dim = X_train.shape[1]))
model.add(Activation({{choice(['tanh','relu', 'sigmoid'])}}))
model.add(Dropout({{uniform(0, 1)}}))
model.add(Dense({{choice([np.power(2,1),np.power(2,2),np.power(2,3),np.power(2,4),np.power(2,5)])}}))
model.add(Activation({{choice(['tanh','relu', 'sigmoid'])}}))
model.add(Dropout({{uniform(0, 1)}}))

# Output layer
model.add(Dense(Y_train.shape[1]))
model.add(Activation('linear'))

model.compile(loss='mae', metrics=['mae'],optimizer=optimizer, loss_weights=[0.6,0.4])

history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train,
          batch_size={{choice([16,32,64,128])}},
          epochs={{choice([20000])}},
          verbose=2,
          validation_data=(X_val, Y_val),
          callbacks=callbacks_list)
```

However, when running this, it says:

```
ValueError: When passing a list as loss_weights, it should have one entry per model output. The model has 1 outputs, but you passed loss_weights=[1, 1]
```

I'm guessing its due to the format of my inputs and outputs. However, I can't figure out the proper format for which I am supposed to feed it into the model.

Appreciate your advice please, thank you.

Comment: Your model has **one output layer** and one loss function. So the `loss_weights` does not make sense here, right? Don't confuse the the shape of output layer which is `(2,)` with the number of output layers. Loss functions are applied on the whole layers' output and not on each element of output layer individually.

Comment: ok so Sequential() cannot have more than one output layer right?

Comment: That's right. You need to use [functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/) instead if you want more flexibility.

Comment: alright, thank you!